# $\int_{-n}^{\infty} e^{-t^2}t^2 dt=?$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Let $n\in \mathbb N.$

$I_n= \int_{-n}^{\infty} e^{-t^2}t^2 dt.$

> Question: Can we compute $I_n$? Where $I_n$ converges as $n\to \infty$?

My try: Put $t^2=y. $ So $I_n= \int_{n^2}^{\infty} e^{-y} y \frac{1}{2t} dy.$  My confusion is: can we write $t=\sqrt{y}$ as $t$ could be negative!!
And so how should I handle this?

I know: $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t}t^{n-1} dt = \Gamma(n).$

Comment: if you accept that $e^{-t^2}$ cannot be integrated without the erf, then you can use integration by parts to make your integral into an integral that only integrates $e^{-t^2}$  - therefore your integral cannot have an expression other than one containing the erf, otherwise integral $e^{-t^2}$  would be able to be expressed in terms of your integral as elementary functions - and it can't

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean exactly by "can we compute $I_n$"? Are you asking if the integral converges or if you can find a closed form expression for it using elementary functions (like polynomials, exponentials, etc).

If you are asking if the integral converges, the answer is **yes**.
If you are asking if there is a closed form expression for it, I strongly believe the answer is **no**, unless you accept using the Gauss function, $erf(x)$, in your solution:

$erf(x)=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$.

Moreover, $\lim_{n \to \infty}I_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.

Comment: @D: Thanks> For fix $n,$  can not we find explicit value of $I_n$?

Comment: @abcd: only for $n=0$. By a change of variable, you can reduce to Gamma, but incomplete Gamma.

Comment: I believe you can if you consider that, for a given $x$, the value of $erf(x)$ is known. Note that, for a given $x$, you can hardly compute $e^x$ without a calculator. Something similar happens with $erf(x)$.

Comment: @YD: Thanks. Can you tell me bit more? How should I prove that we can not evolute $I_n$? (I am curious to know...)

Comment: I believe there is no proof for that. A paradigmatic example is the computation of $\int \frac{sin(x)}{x} dx$. As far as I know, there is no formal proof that no elementary primitive exists, but people have studied well enough to understand that no integration technique may be applied in that case.